# Php autoloading not working in symfony dispatcher example

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to just check out the symfony event dispatcher class and i have been following this online tutorial , so i have the following in my `index.php` file:

```
<?php


require('vendor/autoload.php');

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher;

$dispatcher->addListener('UserSignedUp' , function(Event $event){
    // die('Handling It !!');

    var_dump($event);

}); 

$event = new App\Events\UserSignedUp( (object) [ 'name' => 'gautam' , 'email' => 'gautamz07@yahoo.com' ] );


$dispatcher->dispatch('UserSignedUp' , $event);
```

and i have the following directory structure:

```
  event_dis
    - app
       - events
         - UserSignUp.php
    - vendor
    - index.php
    - composer.json
```

I have the following in my composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^3.2"
    },

    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "App\\" : "app/"
        }
    }

}
```

The UserSignedUp.php class looks like the following :

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;


class UserSignedUp extends Event {
    public $user;
    public function __construct($user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

}
```

Now since i have the following line in my index.php file:

```
$event = new App\Events\UserSignedUp( (object) [ 'name' => 'gautam' , 'email' => 'gautamz07@yahoo.com' ] );
```

The `UserSignedUp` class gets called and i get the following error in my browser:

```
Class 'App\Events\Event' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony_compo\event_dis\app\Events\UserSignedUp.php on line 6
```

Now why am i getting this error , in the tutorial this same example works perfectly, but on my local machine this does't , can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong here ??

Comment: Does the "Event" class exists in `App\Events` namespace ?

Comment: Is there a file app/Events/Event.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Event` class does not exists in `App\Events` namespace. You should edit `UserSignedUp.php` and add `use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class UserSignedUp extends Event {
    public $user;
    public function __construct($user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: just an additinaly question ... how is the file Events.php autoloaded into `UserSignedUp.php` ??

Comment: > "how is the file Events.php autoloaded into UserSignedUp.php" -> It's autoloaded because your autoloader is already included juste before: you called `index.php` which requires the autoloader, then you wrote `new App\Events\UserSignedUp` which use the autoloader, so it requires `UserSignedUp.php` and when you call `extends Event` it still use the previously included autoloader. Not sure if it's clear enough, sorry if not